# HtmlNode Select img where alt equals value

Tags: c#, html, linq, html-agility-pack

I want to select the image's `src` where the img's `alt` is equal to a given value. Below I have given the html I want to extract the image from:

```
<div class="col-md-4 cush">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8">
        <div class="ps4 cush">
            <img src="https://website/assets/img/Anim-img/platforms/PS4-logo.png" alt=PS4 id="platformImage">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <img src="IMAGE_I_WANT_TO_GET" alt=The Alternative>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following which I thought would return the correct value:

```
        originalDetails.CoverImage = htmlNode.SelectNodes($"//img[contains(@alt, '{What i'm trying to match}')]")
              .Select(x => x.GetAttributeValue("src", ""))
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

However I am getting an error `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source`. Is there an easier way to get an image's source by whether or not the image's `alt` equals a given value?

Comment: HTML you've posted is not exactly ideal... Agility pack will try to parse `alt=The Alternative` in some way... but non-quoted attributes, especially with spaces, not necessary get parsed the way you would like...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov `<img src=IMAGE I WANT TO GET alt=The Alternative>` is not the real value of that image, I have replaced the real image `url` and `alt` with the above.

Comment: Can you post a complete working example of the problem? Would be great if it compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wanting to know how I got the image source, I did the following.

```
// Get all the img tags in the node (two in this case) 
var images = htmlNode.Descendants("img").ToArray();

// Image source
// we know that we do NOT want the first image, just the second and that the first 
// attribute in that second image is the image source (what we want).
// So we get the 2nd image and the first attribute of that image
originalDetails.CoverImage = images[1].Attributes.FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

I know it's not the best of ways but it gets the job done.